# How to create a larger symbol?

Tags: symbols, scaling

How can I insert a larger symbol of `textreferencemark`. Exactly how can I use a larger font for the the output of the command

```
\textbf{\textreferencemark}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Exactly the size you want if you use a vector font. Here is how to type it in `48 pt`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern, textcomp}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

{\color{IndianRed}\fontsize{48}{48}\selectfont \textreferencemark} Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can easily scale any symbol (math or text) using [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)'s `\scalebox` or `\resizebox` macros:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, textcomp}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\scalebox{5}{\textcolor{IndianRed}{\textbf{\textreferencemark}}}
\resizebox{2\baselineskip}{!}{\textcolor{IndianRed}{\textbf{\textreferencemark}}}
{\textcolor{IndianRed}{\textbf{\textreferencemark}}}
Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.

\end{document}
```